# Авторизация в vk

Tags: авторизация, вконтакте, php

Привет всем. Остались ли рабочие скрипты авторизации в vk? Про api знаю, он не подходит, потому что в нём нет кое-каких специфичных функций

**Обновление**

Распишу, что мне нужно. Мне нужно устроить поиск по группам. В api есть метод groups.search, но в нем нет фильтрации по параметрам country, city, а это мне как раз и нужно.

Comment: Каких? В нем, по-вашему, нет авторизации? API это скрипт?

Comment: Хорошо, распишу, что мне нужно. Мне нужно устроить поиск по группам. В api есть метод groups.search, но в нем нет фильтрации по параметрам country, city, а это мне как раз и нужно.

Comment: @thetur [да вы что](https://vk.com/dev/groups.search)

> qSearch query string. | string, required parameter  
> type                  | string  
> **country_id**            | positive number  
> **city_id**               | positive number

Comment: о_О откуда инфа?
https://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=groups.search
тут ни слова об этом
но спасибо, работает

Comment: @thetur на "да вы что" кликните

Comment: @thetur на вики-страницах нередко встречается устаревшая информация. Старайтесь использовать документацию из раздела http://vk.com/dev.